# Compare string loaded with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I folks, I have following javascript function, which should check for the index of a column in a table. The problem is the comparison of the columnName and the name from the table.
I have tested with columnName 'ID' and this column is found in the table, but the comparison is not true, so that the index is not returned.

My code:

```
function getColumnIndex(columnName, grid) {
    console.log("loading column index for column: [" + columnName + "]");
    $('div.hDivBox > table > thead > tr > th', grid).each(function(index) {
         var name = $(this).attr('title');
         console.log("Checking cell: [" + name + "]");
         if (String(name) == columnName) {
              return index;
         }
    });
    console.log("no cell found with name: " + columnName);
    return -1;
}
```

The log statements:

> loading column index for column: [ID]
>   Checking cell: [ID]
>   Checking cell: [Name]
>   Checking cell: [Description]
>   Checking cell: [AddTime]
>   Checking cell: [UpdTime]
>   no cell found with name: ID

An example of the HTML, which is analyzed by the javascript function:

```
<div class="hDivBox">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" hidden="" axis="col0" title="ID" style="display: none;">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 30px;">ID</div>
            </th>
            <th align="center" axis="col1" title="Name" class="">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 250px;">Name</div>
            </th>
            <th align="center" axis="col2" title="Description" class="">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 250px;">Beschreibung</div>
            </th>
            <th align="center" axis="col3" title="AddTime">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 120px;">hinzugefügt</div>
            </th>
            <th align="center" axis="col4" title="UpdTime">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 120px;">aktualisiert</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `String(name)` as it's already a string. Also, be sure when you are talking about ID, name and title - they are all different attributes!

Comment: weird. Just in case, I'd try `String(name) == String(columnName)` though I doubt that'll change anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function fails to return element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569516/javascript-function-fails-to-return-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to match the title and use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) instead of looping yourself.

```
function getIndexByTitle( title ) {
 return $('th[title="' + title + '"]').index();
}

alert(getIndexByTitle("ID"));
alert(getIndexByTitle("Name"));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CYJdK/)

Comment: Didn't know that function. Thanks for this smart solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `return` statement inside the anonymous function passed to the `.each()` jQuery function only returns from **that** function, it won't also return from the `getColumnIndex()` function.

Instead, I'd do the following:

```
function getColumnIndex(columnName, grid) {
    console.log("loading column index for column: [" + columnName + "]");
    var index = -1;
    $('div.hDivBox > table > thead > tr > th', grid).each(function(i) {
        var name = $(this).attr('title');
        console.log("Checking cell: [" + name + "]");
        if (String(name) == columnName) {
            index = i;
            return;
        }
    });
    if(index == -1)
        console.log("no cell found with name: " + columnName);
    return index;
}
```

The basic principle is that, rather than returning the index from the anonymous function, you're simply storing the correct index in a variable that's scoped outside of it, so you have access to it after the `.each()` call has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) with a function

```
.each(function(){
    ...
    return index;
});
return -1;
```

This will return from the callback (and maybe stop the each-loop if `index` was `false`), but never break out and return from the outer `getColumnIndex` function! So, that one will always return `-1`.

Quick fix:

```
function getColumnIndex(columnTitle, grid) {
    var index = -1;
    $('div.hDivBox > table > thead > tr:first > th', grid).each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).attr('title') == columnTitle) {
            index = i;
            return false; // break each-loop
        }
    });
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from the inner function which is called in the `each` iteration. You need to save the index outside of the each call to access it afterwards.

```
function getColumnIndex(columnName, grid) {
    var columnIndex;
    console.log("loading column index for column: [" + columnName + "]");
    $('div.hDivBox > table > thead > tr > th', grid).each(function(index) {
         var name = $(this).attr('title');
         console.log("Checking cell: [" + name + "]");
         if (String(name) == columnName) {
              columnIndex = index;
              // return false to exit the each iteration early
              return false;
         }
    });

    if (typeof columnIndex !== "undefined") {
        return columnIndex;
    };

    console.log("no cell found with name: " + columnName);
    return -1;
}
```