# Javascript function always returns null

Tags: javascript

I am newbie to the JavaScript world. I have a doubt how the return statement works in JavaScript.

What I am trying to do is to have a function pass one arguments `param` and looking whether the `param` match the key of the `exampleData` object. If match found I want to return the value and break the looping of each function also break the function I don't want to execute any other statement under the each function. If no match found the function must return null. But currently the function always return null value.

```
function exampleFunction(param){
    $.each(exampleData, function (key, value) {
        if(key == param){
        return value;
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Any insight into this would highly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that key and param match?  Also, are you sure that value isn't null?

Comment: Your `return value;` is in a different function. Just use a `for-in` loop instead.

Comment: You don't need to do all this.  `exampleData[param]` does almost the same thing.  It is equal to `undefined` when param is not in exampleData

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery each - Stop loop and return object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224375/jquery-each-stop-loop-and-return-object)

Comment: @Paul is right. There's no need to loop at all, unless you actually need to the type coercion of the `==` operator.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Yes I am sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function fails to return element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569516/javascript-function-fails-to-return-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example doesn't seem to need a loop. That and returning from the loop-delegate doesn't do anything for you.

You can test if a key appears in an object using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```
function exampleFunction(param){
  return param in exampleData ? exampleData[param] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Given Crazy Train's comment, you need to capture the matching value so you can return it later:

```
function exampleFunction(param) {
    var match = null;
    $.each(exampleData, function (key, value) {
        if (key == param) {
            match = value;
            return false; // to end the $.each early
        }
    });
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Extra +1 for ending the each

Comment: There is no need to loop through exampleData.

Comment: Unless you want to modify the value before returning it

Comment: Modifying the value makes no difference.

Comment: I just offered the easiest correction to the OP's train of thought; I definitely agree that there are better solutions posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function exampleFunction(param){ 
    return exampleData[param];
  }
```

EDIT:  If you want to return null if the parameter is undefined, then take a look at Paul and Crazy Train's comments:

```
return (typeof exampleData[param] === 'undefined')? null: exampleData[param];
```

OR

```
return (param in exampleData) ? exampleData[param] : null;
```

Comment: If it is null, it returns null.  If it is undefined, it returns undefined.

Comment: So if he wants null, the you need to test if it exists

Comment: `return (typeof exampleData[param] === 'undefined')? null: exampleData[param];`

Comment: Correct.  So he would add that condition before the return, and return null if it doesn't exist.  Assuming that's what he wants to do.

Comment: `return (param in exampleData) ? exampleData[param] : null;`

Comment: No need to copy everybody else's answers into yours

Comment: @mplungjan They are good suggestions, so I edited my answer to reflect that.  No harm in expanding on an answer.

Comment: I guess since `null == undefined` that's quite irrelevant

Comment: Unless the caller is testing `=== null`.

Comment: Testing for `typeof x[key] === "undefined"` can have unexpected results. It may be that the key is present but its _value_ has been set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your approach:

1. The inner function you defined is `return`ing to `$.each`, not to the outer function, so you never get that value.
2. You don't need to iterate over the object in the wild way you are. Objects in Javascript are hash tables, you can simply do the following

:

```
function exampleFunction(param) {
    return exampleData[param];
}
```

If `exampleData[param]` is `undefined`, it will return `undefined`, otherwise, it will return the value stored there.

If you absolutely need the undefined case to return `null` instead of `undefined`, then it becomes a bit more complicated.

```
function exampleFunction(param) {
    if(exampleData.hasOwnProperty(param) {
        return exampleData[param];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```